# How can I create an Instance of NSManagedObject in a NotesApp without a Button - Apple's NoteApp Style?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, swift5

I started learning programming and I decided to try out my first Note Taking App.

**My Goal** is to create an App similar to the iPhone's NoteApp. Therefore, I wanted the note's title be set when the User writes in the TextView as the first line. Therefore, I created a `NoteViewController`, which contains a TextView and a `NoteIndexViewController`, which is a `TableViewController`, both embedded in a `NavigationController`.

I'm also using **Core Data** to store the data.

**The problem** is that I don't know how I can commit those changes to the DataBase without using a button. I know how to create an instance of the `NSManagedObject` - in `NoteIndexViewController` to create new notes in the `TableView` using a Button:

```
@IBAction func addNotePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let newNoteIndex = NoteIndex(context: self.context)
        newNoteIndex.name = "Temporal Name"
        notesArray.append(newNoteIndex)

        saveNoteIndex()

        performSegue(withIdentifier: K.segueToNote, sender: self)
 }
```

But I'm completely lost if I want to commit the changes without a "Save Button" to create the instance and also committing changes. This is the code I got so far. **Notice** that I did not set any `Note()` object.

```
class NoteViewController: UIViewController {
    var noteArray = [Note]()

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

   var selectedNote: NoteIndex? {
        didSet {
          loadData()
        }
    }

    var firstLine: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadData()

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)

        if !textView.text.isEmpty {
            if let newLine = textView.text.firstIndex(of: "\n") {
                let firstLetter = textView.text.startIndex
                let lineBrake = textView.text.index(before: newLine)
                let lettersTillPosition = textView.text.distance(from: firstLetter, to: lineBrake)
                firstLine = (textView.text as NSString).substring(to: lettersTillPosition)
            } else {
                if textView.text.count >= 30{
                firstLine = (textView.text as NSString).substring(to: 30)
               } else {
                firstLine = (textView.text as NSString).substring(to: textView.text.count)
               }
           }
            selectedNote!.name = firstLine
            saveCurrentNote()
       }
    }


    //MARK: - Data Manipulation Methods

    func saveCurrentNote() {

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving cateogry \(error)")
        }
    }

    func loadData(with request: NSFetchRequest<Note> = Note.fetchRequest()) {

// goToIndex is the relationship between the IndexNote entity and Note. And when Back button is pressed the code tend also to break in this part. 


            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "goToIndex.name MATCHES %@", selectedNote!.name!)


        do {
            noteArray = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("This is a load error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}


extension NoteViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        saveCurrentNote()
    }

}
```

Comment: I am a little confused as to why you'd like to commit the data when the user hasn't decided to save yet? Is this suppose to function as some sort of temporary cache? I mean I suppose you could use the delegate methods on the textView and create the NSManagedObject when changes are made to that field but I feel like that would be overkill to be honest. I remember when I was making my first note app I simply had a managedObject be created if the user's session was interrupted by a phone call or terminated. Then on relaunch the data would be retrieved and deleted from coredata.

Comment: If you notice - in Apple's notes-  when a new note is created in a tableView, a Cell is created and a segue to a TextView is performed and if the user don't write anything the note gets deleted but if the user writes something then the note is saved. I want to achieve that exact behaviour, the problem is that I don't know where exactly to create the NSManagedObject and also pass the data in the TextView.I suppose that if the user leaves the note empty then it would be a sort of temporary cache. I don't know if I've been clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution for your question. You can use Notification Center to monitor if the user is interrupted and if so you can do a quick save.

Place these in the scene delegate

```
func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {

        let notificationName = NSNotification.Name(ReuseIdentifier.pause)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName , object: nil)
    }

func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {

        let notificationName = NSNotification.Name(ReuseIdentifier.quit)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
    }
```

Place something like this where the user data is being saved.

```
/// Monitors application state for major changes.
    /// - Pause Observer: Adds observer that notifies application if application is no longer active (enters foreground).
    /// - Quit Observer: Adds observer that notifies application if terminated.
    private func checkForPauseOrQuit(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(autoSave),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name(ReuseIdentifier.pause),
                                               object: nil)


        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(autoSave),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name(ReuseIdentifier.quit),
                                               object: nil)
    }
```

And then for your selector method you create your NSManagedObject and capture whatever values the user may have started typing.

On startup you do the reverse, and make sure to erase the values. This should function only as a temporary holding container not your main entity. Check out my note application for reference:

https://github.com/victis23/AwesomeNote/tree/WorkingBranch/AwesomeNote